# Jmeter report Graph with "Number of Users" Vs "Average Response Time"

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there any report /Graph available in JMETER where I could see Number of user at a time Vs the response time of application under test. This will help me identify what is the performance of application at particular load

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is available in JMeter plugins.

Check this link.

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/

It has very clear instruction.

1. Download the latest jar files from the above link
2. Place them under %JMETER_HOME%/lib/ext folder
3. You will see new listeners (after restarting JMeter)

[image]